# Can homebrew update a formula and can it manage multiple versions?

Tags: homebrew

I currently have Scala 2.9.0.1 installed and see that Scala 2.9.1 was released fairly recently. I want to upgrade. However, from what I'm seeing, I don't think homebrew supports upgrading formulae.

I see that "Multiple Version Support" is on the [homebrew wishlist](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Wishlist), but I wonder if this is up-to-date and/or much of an indication of future priorities for the project. I did a quick look at tickets in the [ticket tracker](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/search?q=multiple+versions) but didn't see anything that jumped out at me.

In my case, I'm going to just install the new version and update my environment variables. That will work I suppose. But I feel like a package manager should help me clean up old versions if I want it to.

Related links from the mailing list archives:

- [I missed how to "brew upgrade outdated" or similar](http://librelist.com/browser//homebrew/2011/7/25/i-missed-how-to-brew-upgrade-outdated-or-similar/)
- [Making upgrades work properly](http://librelist.com/browser//homebrew/2010/9/13/making-upgrades-work-properly/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No to both (automatic updating and multiple version management) per https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Wishlist